Issues Processing Advanced LaTeX Math Expressions with latex2sympy
I'm working on a project where I need to process LaTeX documents, particularly the mathematical expressions, and convert them into symbolic representations using latex2sympy. While the library works for many basic expressions, I'm encountering issues with more complex LaTeX notations, such as definitions, sets, and expressions with primes or Greek letters.
Here’s an example of the LaTeX input I'm processing:
``
\begin{definition}{}
Given $G=(V,E,\mu)$, and $W\subseteq V$, we define the \emph{clone of $G$ by duplication of $W$}, $Cl_G^W$, as:
$$Cl_G^W=(V \cup W', E \cup E', \mu \cup \{(n', \mu(n))\}_{n \in W} \cup \{(e', \mu(e))\}_{e' \in E'})$$
where $W' = \{n'\ :\ n \in W\}$ are new cloned nodes from $W$, and $E'$ is a set of new edges obtained from incident edges on nodes of $W$ where nodes of $W$ are replaced by copies of $W'$ (edges connecting original nodes with cloned nodes and edges connecting cloned nodes, are cloned).

\end{definition}
``
To process this, I wrote a Python script that uses latex2sympy. Here's the main part of my code:
from latex2sympy2 import latex2sympy
import re
import sympy as sp
import logging

class LatexProcessor:
    def _convert_equations_to_text(self, latex_text, processed_text):
        equation_pattern = re.compile(r'\$.*?\$|\$\$.*?\$\$|\\\\\[.*?\\\\\]|\\\\\(.*?\\\\\)', re.DOTALL)
        equations = equation_pattern.findall(latex_text)

        for equation in equations:
            try:
                equation_clean = equation.strip("$").strip("\\[").strip("\\]").strip("\\(").strip("\\)").strip()
                if not equation_clean.strip():
                    raise ValueError("Empty equation")

                equation_clean = equation_clean.replace("\\subseteq", "<=")
                equation_clean = re.sub(r"\\\\\{(.*?)\\\\\}", r"Set(\1)", equation_clean)

                if "=" in equation_clean:
                    sides = equation_clean.split("=", 1)
                    lhs = sp.sympify(sides[0].strip())
                    rhs = sp.sympify(sides[1].strip())
                    sympy_expr = sp.Eq(lhs, rhs)
                else:
                    sympy_expr = latex2sympy(equation_clean)

                processed_equation = f"[Processed Equation: {sympy_expr}]"
            except Exception as e:
                logging.warning(f"Could not process equation: {equation}. Error: {e}")
                processed_equation = f"[Unprocessed Equation: {equation}]"

            processed_text += f"\n{processed_equation}\n"

        return processed_text


The issues I'm encountering include:

Prime notation (n'): The library throws errors like:

SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (detected at line 1)

Greek letters (\mu): These are not parsed correctly by latex2sympy.

Set notation ({...}): These are challenging to process and often result in parsing errors.

General parsing errors: Some expressions result in vague errors like:

Sympify of expression 'could not parse ...' failed.

Additional Context:
I am open to using other Python libraries or even entirely different approaches to convert mathematical LaTeX expressions into plain text or symbolic representations. My goal is to make this process as robust and versatile as possible for a wide variety of LaTeX expressions.
Question:
How can I improve my processing pipeline to handle these advanced LaTeX expressions effectively? Are there better tools, libraries, or preprocessing strategies to achieve this?
Thank you in advance for any help or advice!
your textIn my current approach to processing LaTeX equations, I’ve used several methods and strategies, which are detailed below:

Regex-based LaTeX Equation Extraction:

I use regular expressions to identify and extract LaTeX equations within the text. This is done using the re library to capture both inline ($...$) and display-style ($$...$$) equations, as well as equations inside [ and ] or ( and ).

Basic Cleaning and Preprocessing:

Once the equations are extracted, I clean them up by stripping unwanted LaTeX syntax (e.g., removing $, \[, \], \(, \)).
I also replace some LaTeX-specific symbols with more readable or equivalent representations, such as:
\alpha → alpha
\mathcal → empty string (since sympy does not recognize this)
\cup → | (for set union)
\in → in (for set membership)
\leq → <=, \geq → >= (for comparison operators)
\times → * (for multiplication)

Handling Special LaTeX Notations:

For expressions that include Greek letters like \mu or other special symbols, I replace them with equivalent text, such as:
\mu → mu
I also handle set notation by preprocessing sets with a regex (\\{...}) and converting them to a more recognizable form (Set(...)).

SymPy Integration for Symbolic Parsing:
For equations that appear simple (e.g., basic algebraic expressions), I use sympy.sympify() to convert them into symbolic representations.
I also handle equations involving equality (=) by splitting them into left-hand side (lhs) and right-hand side (rhs), then parsing each side separately before forming a sympy.Eq() object for symbolic equality.

Latex2Sympy for More Complex Equations:


For more complex LaTeX expressions that involve set operations or other advanced notations, I pass the cleaned-up equation to latex2sympy().ç

Error Handling and Logging:

I include try-except blocks to catch errors during the parsing process and log any issues, allowing me to track which equations failed to be processed. If an equation cannot be processed, I append it as unprocessed text to the output.
Despite these efforts, I still encounter issues with advanced LaTeX notations, such as:

Prime notation (e.g., n'): SymPy and latex2sympy throw errors when handling primes, often with a syntax error related to unterminated string literals.
Greek letters (e.g., \mu): These are not consistently parsed correctly by latex2sympy.
Set notation (e.g., {...}): While I use regex to replace these, some expressions still fail or are parsed incorrectly.
General parsing issues: Some complex LaTeX expressions result in vague parsing errors from SymPy, such as "Sympify of expression 'could not parse ...' failed."

Goals:
I aim to improve the robustness and versatility of this process to handle more complex and diverse LaTeX expressions. While I have explored regex preprocessing and basic SymPy handling, I believe I could further improve the parsing pipeline, especially for advanced LaTeX notations such as prime notations, Greek letters, and set expressions. I'm open to using other libraries or approaches that might improve parsing accuracy and handle edge cases better.

I think latex2sympy was basically merged into sympy itself which has a parse_latex function now. There is also a new lark-based version of the LaTeX parser that you can try.
